# Replacing multiple numeric columns with the log value of those columns Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a pandas DataFrame in Python that has 10 variables (4 numeric, 6 categorical). I want to replace the values of the 4 numeric variables with the natural log of the current values.

Example of my data below:

df = DataFrame

logcolumns = the names of the columns that I want to convert to the natural log

```
Import numpy as np
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
logcolumns = ['Volume', 'Sales', 'Weight', 'Price']
df[logcolumns] = np.log(df[logcolumns])
```

After running this, I receive a SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

This process works with an individual column, and with an entire dataframe, but not when I try to run it on a list of selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow up the suggestion inside the warning and use labelled based access:

```
df.loc[:, logcolumns] = np.log(df[logcolumns])
```

The official doc is here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Still receive the same copy error, but I will just check the values to ensure it is calculating correctly